# How to send form fields and a file using PHP Curl?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send form fields and file to a web service using php curl. The form has already been passed from a browser to a proxy php client web app and I'm trying to forward it to the web service.

When I pass an array to curl_setopt like this:

`curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->fields);`

I get a Array to String notice although it is meant to take an array. Here's my array that is passed to $this->fields in the constructor.

```
$fields = array('title'=>$title,
'content'=>$content,
'category'=>$category,
'attachment'=>$_FILES['attachment']);
```

If I pass a string using `http_build_query` my web serivce complains about not having  multipart/form data.

If I then force the multipart/form enctype using `curl_setopt` I get an error saying there's no boundary:

`org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array to string notice you have with the following code :

```
$fields = array(
  'title'=>$title,
  'content'=>$content,
  'category'=>$category,
  'attachment'=>$_FILES['attachment']
);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

is not because of you're passing an array as 3rd parameter to curl_setopt : it's because you're passing an array for `attachment`.

If you want to pass a file this way, you should pass its absolute path, pre-pending a `@` before it :

```
$fields = array(
  'title'=>$title,
  'content'=>$content,
  'category'=>$category,
  'attachment'=> '@' . $_FILES['attachment']
);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

*(This is supposing that `$_FILES['attachment']` contains the full path to your file -- up to you to change this code so it's using the right data, if needed)*

As a reference, quoting the manual page of [**`curl_setopt`**][1], for the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option :

The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation.

**To post a file, prepend a filename with `@` and use the full path.**

This can either be passed as a urlencoded string like `'para1=val1&para2=val2&...'` or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value.

If value is an array, the `Content-Type` header will be set to `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now passing in the filename with the @ but I'm still getting the multipart boundary error.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$filePath = "abc\\xyz.txt";         

$postParams["uploadfile"] = "@" . $filePath;


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://website_address');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postParams);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch))
            {
                echo curl_error($ch);               
                exit();                         
            }
        curl_close($ch);
```